# Error using ExpandoObject in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, expandoobject

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I am using the `ExpandoObject` in my app. Currently, I have the following block in my .cshtml file:

```
foreach (System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject expo in ViewBag.ExpandoObjects)
{
  <div>@filter.GetType().FullName</div>
}
```

This code works fine. In fact, it prints out `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject` onto the screen like I'd expect. However, when I update the code to the following, I get an error.

```
foreach (System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject expo in ViewBag.ExpandoObjects)
{
  foreach (var key in expo.Keys) 
  {
    <div>@key</div>
  }
}
```

The error says:

```
CS1061: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Keys' and no extension method 'Keys' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I do not understand why I'm getting this error. According to the documentation, there is a [Keys property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630187(v=vs.110).aspx). What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Keys` property is explicitly implemented for the `IDictionary` interface. This, for example, won't compile:

```
Console.WriteLine(new ExpandoObject().Keys);
```

If you want to use `Keys` you'll have to cast it as an `IDictionary`.

```
foreach (System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject expo in ViewBag.ExpandoObjects)
{
  foreach (var key in ((IDictionary<string, object>)expo).Keys) 
  {
    <div>@key</div>
  }
}
```

If you want to access a key by a name you know at compile-time, you can either use a dictionary indexer or cast the object as `dynamic`.

```
foreach (IDictionary<string, object> expo in ViewBag.ExpandoObjects)
{
    <div>@expo["name"]</div>
```

or

```
foreach (dynamic expo in ViewBag.ExpandoObjects)
{
    <div>@expo.name</div>
```

Here's a brief code snippet to give you an idea of how to work with an ExpandoObject cast as an `ExpandoObject`, `dynamic`, or `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
var obj = new ExpandoObject();
var dict = ((IDictionary<string, object>)obj);
var dyn = (dynamic) obj;
dyn.name = "Fred";
Console.WriteLine(dyn.name);  // "Fred"
var key = dict.Keys.Single();
Console.WriteLine(key);       // "name"
Console.WriteLine(dict[key]); // "Fred"
```

Note that I strongly advise you use strongly-typed view models if at all possible. `dynamic` typing is good for what it's made for, but will kill maintainability if overused.

Comment: When I do this, I see "name" in the list. But, if I say `<div>@expo.name</div>` I get an error that says `CS1061: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' could be found`. I don't get it. How do I get a property value out of an `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: @xamdeveloper: If you want to treat it as a dynamic object, you need to cast it as `dynamic`.